# Could not find gradle-3.5.0.jar

Tags: android, flutter

After adding the image_picker to my flutter project. The project started to fail building and gave me the following:

```
flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:classpath'. > Could not find gradle-3.5.0.jar
```

after doing an extended research on how to solve the problem, I tried the following:

- upgrading flutter
- change the  compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 29
- flutter clean
- enabling multiDexEnabled
- flutter pub cache repair

none of the above mentioned methods solved the problem.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `settings.gradle`? It can be found inside the `android/app` directory

Comment: include ':app'

def localPropertiesFile = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "local.properties")
def properties = new Properties()

assert localPropertiesFile.exists()
localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader -> properties.load(reader) }

def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
apply from: "$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of trying different things, I did the following since same problems used to happen to me while I used to work on Android native:

- I just deleted the .gradle folder and it solved the problem.

I don't exactly know what is the reason, but if I have to guess I think it's related to network issues while making gradle build.